# How to cut a compound path of several objects that share a gradient and keep it shared

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, gradient

Whenever I cut an object within a compound path, the gradient that was applied across all of them gets reapplied to them individually.  How can I stop this from happening? I'm using the newest version of illustrator

Answer (score 1):

Kill the unwanted parts in the isolation mode:

[image]