# Making a gradient out of a custom swatch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I have a pattern made and saved as a swatch.  I would like to have this pattern fade from full opacity on the left to full transparency on the right.  However, I can't pull up my swatch in the gradient panel so how can 
I create this effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround:

You can make an opacity mask for the shape filled with your custom patterns. For that open the Transparency panel

- make an outline that is equal with your filled shape, but empty. Let's call it S for clarity
- fill S with a black to white gradient.
- move S onto your pattern filled shape
- select both shapes
- click the panel menu icon in the right top corner of the transparency panel
- click Make Opacity Mask

You're ready.

Be sure to open the transparency panel options visible. From there you can easily invert the mask.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know the solution to this other problem I'm having?: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86629/how-to-cut-a-compound-path-of-several-objects-that-share-a-gradient-and-keep-it

Comment: @JasonMonsalve one answer is ready